# Kotlin Reflection - Check if property has type

Tags: reflection, kotlin

I want to iterate over all fields in one of my classes, filter for annotated ones and then check if the field has one specific type. 
All I found was `field.returnType.isSubtype(other: KType)` but I don't know how to get the `KType` of my other class.

Here is my code so far:

```
target.declaredMemberProperties.forEach {
    if (it.findAnnotation<FromOwner>() != null) {
        if ( /*  it.returnType is Component <- Here I need some working check   */ ) {

            // do stuff
         } else {

            // do ther stuff
         }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are at least two solutions here:

- Get the `KClass<*>` of `it.returnType` using [`.jvmErasure`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.reflect.jvm/jvm-erasure.html), then check the subtype relationship for the `KClass`es:

  ```
  it.returnType.jvmErasure.isSubclassOf(Component::class)
  ```
- Since Kotlin 1.1, you can construct the `KType` from the `KClass` token using [`.createType()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.reflect.full/create-type.html) (check its optional parameters: you can use them to provide nullability info, type arguments and annotations), and then check the subtype as you suggested:

  ```
  it.returnType.isSubtypeOf(Component::class.createType())
  ```

  <sup>Creating the type on every iteration may introduce performance issues, make sure you cache it if you need it often.</sup>

Comment: does this mean it would be a good idea to have `val componentType by lazy { Component::class.createType() }` in a companion object?

Comment: @Exhauzt, I guess benchmarking your particular use case should give the best answer here.